# Why is my captivate able to run flash on android 2.1?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, 2.1-eclair, adobe-flash

I just noticed that my Captivate can play some flash videos, animations, and to an extent, flash games using the stock android browser running android 2.1. It is incredibly slow and takes forever to load, but it does work as far as i could tell (although incredibly slowly and it uses huge amounts of CPU before it finishes loading...almost like it is recompiling the flash application before running it).

My phone status still says that my phone is running 2.1 eclair and I thought that only 2.2 could run flash. Also I haven't downloaded the flash 10.1 application yet either.

What is going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Samsung put the "Flash Lite" plugin on the Galaxy S for 2.1.  It supports the basics.  This blog shows some devices that use the plugin: http://www.adobe-flashlite.com/

Edit: Adobe now has a list of devices that can run full Flash.  http://www.adobe.com/flashplatform/certified_devices/

Comment: So this is a samsung specific feature? How dose the plugin work? Is it actually recompiling the application before running it?

Comment: I don't believe there's any recompilation - full Flash 10.1 is also very slow on my Galaxy S with 2.2.  I've added a link to a blog that lists some devices with Flash Lite.